# Cipher Feedback Mode: s-bit size confusion

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I'm new to Crypto and am trying to make a block cipher encryption program. And I've stumbled across a doubt while writing the CFB part.

Supposing we have a 64-bit block cipher with. And we use 7-bit CFB along with it. Then, for each block, the block will be run nine times wherein nine 7-bit left shifts to the block (starting with IV) and subsequent additions take place.

This means after 9 rounds of CFB, 63 bits of the 64-bit block are processed. At the end we have one bit remaining. How do I process this bit? Do I take seven bits again or just encrypt the one remaining bit?

I have this same question for any case where the *s* is not a factor of the block size.

Comment: The simplest mode is ECB.  Better to start with that, since the other modes are built on top of ECB.  Once you have ECB working, then extend to CBC and CTR, which are probably a bit easier than CFB.

Comment: Generally CFB is only used in 8 and n-bit mode (where n is the block size). Bit level operations are really never used, even though the ciphers have been specified using bit ops. 1 bit mode could be a thing, but in that case you'd never run into trouble either. So just indicate that your "s" must always be 8 or 64 bits and you're done. The answer is undoubtedly that you need to take another 7 bits by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back, this question seems silly.

I've now understood that the plaintext, if it's length isn't a multiple of the block size, must be padded to be so.